# How can I conform DocumentSnapshot to protocol Decodable / Encodable

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The idea is a user will get 5 docs at a time paginated and the last of each 5 docs' snapshot will be saved to the users document for use if the user exists the app. I am trying to store a DocumentSnapshot in a firebase doc in order to know what document the user last viewed. I am using a .start(afterDocument: ) on my query to get the docs.

The problem is I cannot get my data model to conform to the correct Codable standard for use. The reason is because of my lastFetchedMediaSnapshot of type Doc snapshot. When I change it to of type doc ref it conforms properly. How can I get my data model to conform to codable while having a var of type doc snapshot?

Here is the model:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore

struct UserModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String
    var fullName: String?
    var birthDate: Date?
    var profilePictureURL: String?
    var hostedStoryIDs: [UserStoryID]?
    var joinedStoryIDs: [UserStoryID]?
    var watchingStoryIDs: [UserStoryID]?
    var savedMediaRefs: [DocumentReference]?
    var lastFetchedMediaSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot?
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case fullName
        case birthDate
        case profilePictureURL
        case hostedStoryIDs
        case joinedStoryIDs
        case watchingStoryIDs
        case savedMediaRefs
        case lastFetchedMediaSnapshot
    }
}

struct UserStoryID: Identifiable, Codable, Equatable {
    var id: String?
    var isLive: Bool?
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case isLive
    }
}
```

Comment: The implication is that DocumentReference and DocumentSnapshot would need to be Codable. Are they?

Comment: @matt DocumentReference in replace of DocumentSnapshot works just fine. DocSnap for some reason does not conform out of the box with CodingKeys, cannot find any doc on how to make it conform

Comment: So maybe your question should be about _that_?

Comment: @matt will edit accordingly

Comment: Does this help? https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=3-yQeAf3bLE

Comment: The objective states *store a DocumentSnapshot in a firebase doc in order to know what document the user last viewed*. Seems overly complex. Why not just store the documentId as String - that's really all that's needed (and common practice)